# posterior covariance for linear inversion

Tags: error-propagation

I am performing a physical experiment where the unavoidably inaccurate setup likely creates errors in the inversion of the data for the model.

Let's assume a linear relationship between data $\mathbf d$ and model $\mathbf m$ as follows: $$\mathbf d = \mathbf W \mathbf m,$$ where $\mathbf W$ is the operator (encoding the setup of my physical experiment). Standard linear inversion yields the model $$\mathbf m = \mathbf {C_m}^{-1} \mathbf W^\prime \mathbf {C_d}^{-1} \mathbf d$$ with the data covariance $\mathbf {C_d}$ and the model covariance $$\mathbf {C_m} = \left( \mathbf W^\prime {\mathbf {C_d}^{-1}} \mathbf W \right)^{-1}.$$ So far, so good.

The operator $\mathbf W = \mathbf W (\mathbf p)$, however, depends in a non-linear way on a parameter $\mathbf p$, but a linearization, say $$\mathbf V = \dfrac {\partial \mathbf W} {\partial \mathbf p} \mathbf {p_0},$$ where $\mathbf {p_0}$ is the a-priori known (measured) parameter, will do.

Now, how do I continue from here? That is how do I account for any (small) parameter uncertainty in the inversion for the model and model covariance?